# Capybara Unable to find field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello  I am doing my very first tests and I would need your help. I am using Rails5.

The problem is because of the nested fields I believe...(used Cocoon gem)

Capybara returns this error:

`Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_first_name"`

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group string optional event_participants_first_name"><label class="control-label string optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_first_name">Participant's first name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="event[participants_attributes][1489697584487][first_name]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_first_name" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>
  <div class="form-group integer optional event_participants_salary"><label class="control-label integer optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_salary">Participant's monthly pay</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="event[participants_attributes][1489697584487][salary]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_salary"></div>
  <div class="links">
    <input type="hidden" name="event[participants_attributes][1489697584487][_destroy]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489697584487__destroy" value="false"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-friend remove_fields dynamic" href="#">Remove this friend</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my features/events/create_event.spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Creating an event" do
  it "redirects on result page on success" do
    visit "/"
    click_link "Create a new event"
    expect(page).to have_content('Wanna share fair?')

    fill_in :name, with: 'Rent a plane'
    fill_in "What is the total price", with: 200
    click_link "Add a participant"


    fill_in "event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_first_name", with: "John"
enter code here
    fill_in ":event_participants_attributes_1489697584487_salary", with: 2300

    click_button "See result"


    expect(page).to have_content('Your salary together:')
 end
end
```

And here are my simple_forms:

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1>Wanna share fair?</h1>
        <p>Create an event, enter the bill to share.</p>

        <%= f.input :name, label: "Event's name" %>

        <%= f.input :total_price, label: "What is the total price" %>

        <p>Add the participants.</p>
        <div id="participants">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :participants do |participant| %>
          <%= render "participants_fields", f: participant %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="links text-center">
            <%= link_to_add_association "Add a participant", f, :participants, partial: "participants_fields", class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-friend" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
      <%= f.submit "See result" , class:"btn btn-success btn-lg btn-event"  %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

_participants_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Participant's first name" %>
  <%= f.input :salary, label: "Participant's monthly pay" %>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove this friend", f , class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-friend" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## edit more html

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_event" id="new_event" action="/events" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="O5XM0JMiVBbpPNaKF1apw7rdtC/XEBhasZQoK6POycZQ2Zp14Td1ljoJyIUKTwtl91LlBHeDkKFtcWRnNu+iEQ==">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1>Wanna share fair?</h1>
        <p>Create an event, enter the bill to share.</p>

        <div class="form-group string optional event_name"><label class="control-label string optional" for="event_name">Event's name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="event[name]" id="event_name" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>

        <div class="form-group integer optional event_total_price"><label class="control-label integer optional" for="event_total_price">What is the total price</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="event[total_price]" id="event_total_price" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>

        <p>Add the participants.</p>
        <div id="participants">
                    <div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group string optional event_participants_first_name"><label class="control-label string optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489705438668_first_name">Participant's first name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705438668][first_name]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705438668_first_name" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>
  <div class="form-group integer optional event_participants_salary"><label class="control-label integer optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489705438668_salary">Participant's monthly pay</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705438668][salary]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705438668_salary" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>
  <div class="links">
    <input type="hidden" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705438668][_destroy]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705438668__destroy" value="false"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-friend remove_fields dynamic" href="#">Remove this friend</a>
  </div>
</div><div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group string optional event_participants_first_name"><label class="control-label string optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489705443842_first_name">Participant's first name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705443842][first_name]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705443842_first_name" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>
  <div class="form-group integer optional event_participants_salary"><label class="control-label integer optional" for="event_participants_attributes_1489705443842_salary">Participant's monthly pay</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705443842][salary]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705443842_salary" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>
  <div class="links">
    <input type="hidden" name="event[participants_attributes][1489705443842][_destroy]" id="event_participants_attributes_1489705443842__destroy" value="false"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-friend remove_fields dynamic" href="#">Remove this friend</a>
  </div>
</div><div class="links text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add-friend add_fields" data-association="participant" data-associations="participants" data-association-insertion-template="<div class=&quot;nested-fields&quot;>
  <div class=&quot;form-group string optional event_participants_first_name&quot;><label class=&quot;control-label string optional&quot; for=&quot;event_participants_attributes_new_participants_first_name&quot;>Participant&amp;#39;s first name</label><input class=&quot;form-control string optional&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;event[participants_attributes][new_participants][first_name]&quot; id=&quot;event_participants_attributes_new_participants_first_name&quot; /></div>
  <div class=&quot;form-group integer optional event_participants_salary&quot;><label class=&quot;control-label integer optional&quot; for=&quot;event_participants_attributes_new_participants_salary&quot;>Participant&amp;#39;s monthly pay</label><input class=&quot;form-control numeric integer optional&quot; type=&quot;number&quot; step=&quot;1&quot; name=&quot;event[participants_attributes][new_participants][salary]&quot; id=&quot;event_participants_attributes_new_participants_salary&quot; /></div>
  <div class=&quot;links&quot;>
    <input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;event[participants_attributes][new_participants][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;event_participants_attributes_new_participants__destroy&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /><a class=&quot;btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove-friend remove_fields dynamic&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>Remove this friend</a>
  </div>
</div>

" href="#">Add a participant</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="See result" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-event" data-disable-with="See result">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the "1489697584487" part of the ids you show is created by Cocoon based on the current timestamp.  That means every time you run your test the number will be different so you're not going to be able to select those elements by id.

Instead if you're only adding one participant you should be able to do something like

```
fill_in "Participant's first name", with: "John"
fill_in "Participant's monthly pay", with: "2300"
```

If you are adding multiple participants then depending on the exact layout you can use nth-child/nth-of-type CSS selectors to scope the fill_in or use `all` and select the one you want, etc.

```
find('.nested-fields:nth-child(2)').fill_in ...
all(:field, "Participant's first name", minimum: 2)[1].set("John") # 0 based index so minimum should be 1 more than the index you want
```

Also - For any of this to work you need to be using a JS capable driver (Cocoon requires JS).  You haven't tagged your spec with `js: true` metadata so either you've overridden the default driver, or you're not currently using a JS capable driver - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver. Also see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup and https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example if you haven't yet configure database_cleaner for use with JS capable drivers

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply!
Errors are different now but i bet i'm too new in rails to understand wha'ts happening...
It asked me to install a `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` I did it but now it ask for:
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
        Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.`
I am not sure where and how to add this...

Comment: @Liwis If you're using macOS you can do `brew install geckodriver`. Otherwise you'll have to do what the instructions tell you - go to the location listed, download the latest release and place it somewhere your system will locate it by default (ie, in one of the directories in your PATH)

Comment: thanks !  I could fix this!
I am still in trouble with:
`Failure/Error: find('.nested-fields:nth-child(2)').fill_in ...

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css ".nested-fields:nth-child(2)"`

Comment: @Liwis Do you have an element that has at least 2 children with the class .nested-fields where one is the 2nd child?  That was an example of one way to scope if/when you have multiple nested-fields elements, but you need to modify it to match whatever your exact HTML is. (Your posted HTML is only a fragment and doesn't show the actual structure when adding multiple participants)

Comment: well I am not sure to understand well...
My form is to create an event (name and total_price)
it has nested fields for participants (first_name and salary)
I can add as many participant as needed. I add  more html in my questoin :)

Comment: @Liwis So in the HTML you now posted, it appears the "Add a participant" button is broken, but assuming you have clicked the 'Add a participant' link twice (which it sort of looks like - formatting the HTML would help) then  `find('.nested-fields:nth-child(2)').fill_in "Participant's first name", with: "John"` should fill in the second participants (:nth-child(2)) first name.

Comment: @Liwis You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.

Comment: I've accepted it, I upvoted too but it's not displaying as I am under 15 points of reputation :( Thanks again and good night :)